# c++ refactoring: change method name, input and output

Tags: c++, eclipse, vim, eclipse-cdt

i'm using eclipse cdt helios. i was using for a long time eclipse for java and i found it a perfect IDE. it could be almost everything and it could resolve a lot of my problem and really improve my speed in coding, and in making elegant code. but in c++ things are different.

i want to know if there are some easy way to refactor: if i change a method input or output in .cpp i want to have changes to be coherent in .h. like if i wanto to change

```
int *test::foo(char x, int y) { .. }
```

into

```
vector<int> test::foo1(chat x, double y) { .. }
```

there 2 changes:

1. outpur from int* to vector
2. name from foo to foo1
3. input from double to int

i want to this changes to affect also .h file. and all occurences of it.

is this possible with eclipse helios cdt? with some other c++ IDE on linux? (for example in vim.. how?)

EDIT: no vim guru around here?

Comment: Give lazy C++ a look http://www.lazycplusplus.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in [QTCreator IDE](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/), you can globally rename variables and change methods.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done particully with Netbeans C++ IDE. There you can find 'Change function parameters' in refactor. But, functionallity is no so good because you can't edit existing paremeters (for example change parameter type), only add, remove and changing place in signature. So, in your case for change 1-st parameter type from char to chat you need to remove 1-st parameter then add parameter with type chat. Also, Netbeans could't refactor return type of function.